BLE Central "failed" to automatically reconnect to a BLE peripheral
Introduction
I'm developing a BLE Central using Zephyr 3.7.0
I can connect, pair and bond to my BLE Peripheral, read and write characteristics. I've set the BLE security to level 3 (Encryption and authentication). So far everything looks great.
Now I'm trying to enable the auto connect feature in my Central. This is where my issue appears.
The bt_le_set_auto_conn() function return 0 (success), I'm sure that the scan parameters are not NULL (was set to BT_LE_CONN_PARAM_DEFAULT). However, when I'm disconnect the peripheral (by moving out of the range or just turning it off and on), the disconnected_cb isn't called, the bt_hci_core warns opcode 0x200e status 0x0c, which is:

opcode 0x200e means BT_HCI_OP_LE_CREATE_CONN_CANCEL
status 0x0c means COMMAND DISALLOWED

Reproductible sample
Here is a minimal reproductible sample:
#include <zephyr/types.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <zephyr/kernel.h>
#include <zephyr/device.h>
#include <zephyr/sys/printk.h>
#include <zephyr/sys/util.h>
#include <zephyr/drivers/gpio.h>

#include <zephyr/logging/log.h>
#include <zephyr/logging/log_ctrl.h>

#include <zephyr/bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/conn.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/uuid.h>
#include <zephyr/bluetooth/gatt.h>
#include <zephyr/sys/byteorder.h>

LOG_MODULE_REGISTER(main, LOG_LEVEL_DBG);

static struct bt_conn *default_conn;

static void start_scan(void);

static bool parse_data_cb(struct bt_data *data, void *user_data)
{
  bt_addr_le_t *addr = user_data;

  switch (data->type)
  {
    case BT_DATA_NAME_SHORTENED:
    case BT_DATA_NAME_COMPLETE:
      ((uint8_t *)data->data)[data->data_len] = '\0';
      LOG_INF("[DEVICE]: %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\tDevice name: %s", addr->a.val[5], addr->a.val[4], addr->a.val[3], addr->a.val[2], addr->a.val[1], addr->a.val[0], data->data);
      if (strncmp(data->data, "MY PERIPHERAL NAME", data->data_len) == 0)
      {
        int err = bt_le_scan_stop();
        if (err)
        {
          LOG_ERR("Stop LE scan failed (err %d)", err);
          return false;
        }

        struct bt_conn_le_create_param *create_param = BT_CONN_LE_CREATE_CONN;
        struct bt_le_conn_param *param = BT_LE_CONN_PARAM_DEFAULT;

        err = bt_conn_le_create(addr, create_param, param, &default_conn);
        if (err)
        {
          LOG_WRN("Connection failed (err %d)", err);
          start_scan();
        }
        err = bt_le_set_auto_conn(addr, param);
        if (err)
        {
          LOG_ERR("Error: bt_le_set_auto_conn() return %d", err);
          start_scan();
        }
        return false;
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return true;
}

static void on_device_found_cb(const bt_addr_le_t *addr, int8_t rssi, uint8_t type, struct net_buf_simple *ad)
{
  if (type == BT_GAP_ADV_TYPE_ADV_IND || type == BT_GAP_ADV_TYPE_ADV_DIRECT_IND || type == BT_GAP_ADV_TYPE_EXT_ADV || type == BT_GAP_ADV_TYPE_SCAN_RSP)
  {
    if (rssi < -30)
    {
      bt_data_parse(ad, parse_data_cb, (void *)addr);
    }
  }
}

static void start_scan(void)
{
  int err;

  struct bt_le_scan_param scan_param = {
    .type       = BT_LE_SCAN_TYPE_ACTIVE,
    .options    = BT_LE_SCAN_OPT_NONE,
    .interval   = BT_GAP_SCAN_FAST_INTERVAL,
    .window     = BT_GAP_SCAN_FAST_WINDOW,
  };

  err = bt_le_scan_start(&scan_param, on_device_found_cb);
  if (err) {
    LOG_ERR("Scanning failed to start (err %d)", err);
    return;
  }

  LOG_INF("Scanning successfully started");
}

static void connected_cb(struct bt_conn *conn, uint8_t conn_err)
{
  const bt_addr_le_t * addr = bt_conn_get_dst(conn);
  int err = 0;

  if (conn_err) {
    LOG_ERR("Failed to connect to %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X (err %u)", addr->a.val[5], addr->a.val[4], addr->a.val[3], addr->a.val[2], addr->a.val[1], addr->a.val[0], conn_err);

    bt_conn_unref(default_conn);
    default_conn = NULL;
    start_scan();
  }
  LOG_INF("Connected: %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", addr->a.val[5], addr->a.val[4], addr->a.val[3], addr->a.val[2], addr->a.val[1], addr->a.val[0]);

  if (conn == default_conn)
  {
    int err = bt_conn_set_security(conn, BT_SECURITY_L3);
    if (err)
      LOG_ERR("Error while pairing %d", err);
  }
}

static void disconnected_cb(struct bt_conn *conn, uint8_t reason)
{
  LOG_DBG("Beginning disconnected_cb");

  const bt_addr_le_t * addr = bt_conn_get_dst(conn);
  if (default_conn != conn)
    return;

  LOG_INF("Disconnected: %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X (reason 0x%02x)", addr->a.val[5], addr->a.val[4], addr->a.val[3], addr->a.val[2], addr->a.val[1], addr->a.val[0], reason);
}

static void auth_passkey_display_cb(struct bt_conn *conn, unsigned int passkey)
{
  LOG_WRN("Passkey is: %06u", passkey);
}

static void auth_passkey_confirm_cb(struct bt_conn *conn, unsigned int passkey)
{
  LOG_WRN("Passkey confirmed");
  bt_conn_auth_passkey_confirm(conn);
}

static void le_param_updated_cb(struct bt_conn *conn, uint16_t interval, uint16_t latency, uint16_t timeout)
{
  LOG_WRN("CONN PARAMS UPDATED  interval %d, latency %d, timeout %d", interval, latency, timeout);
}

static bool le_param_req_cb(struct bt_conn *conn, struct bt_le_conn_param *param)
{
  LOG_WRN("CONN PARAMS UPDATE REQUESTED  interval_min %d, interval_max %d, latency %d, timeout %d", param->interval_min, param->interval_max, param->latency, param->timeout);

  return true;
}

BT_CONN_CB_DEFINE(conn_callbacks) = {
    .connected = connected_cb,
    .disconnected = disconnected_cb,
    .le_param_req = le_param_req_cb,
    .le_param_updated = le_param_updated_cb,
};

static void pairing_complete(struct bt_conn *conn, bool bonded)
{
  if (bonded)
    LOG_DBG("Pairing complete");
  else
    LOG_DBG("Pairing failed");
}

static struct bt_conn_auth_cb conn_auth_callbacks = {
  .passkey_display = auth_passkey_display_cb,
  .passkey_confirm = auth_passkey_confirm_cb,
  .cancel = auth_cancel_cb,
};

static struct bt_conn_auth_info_cb auth_info_cb = {
  .pairing_complete = pairing_complete
};

int main(void)
{
  LOG_INIT();

  int err = bt_conn_auth_cb_register(&conn_auth_callbacks);
  bt_conn_auth_info_cb_register(&auth_info_cb);

  // Init Bluetooth subsystem
  err = bt_enable(NULL);
  if (err)
  {
    LOG_ERR("Bluetooth init failed (err %d)", err);
    return  1;
  }

  bt_set_bondable(true);
  LOG_INF("Bluetooth initialized");

  start_scan();

  return 0;
}

Using this Zephyr KConfig
CONFIG_BT=y
CONFIG_BT_DEVICE_NAME="test"
CONFIG_BT_CENTRAL=y
CONFIG_BT_GATT_CLIENT=y
CONFIG_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_GPIO=y
CONFIG_SERIAL=y
CONFIG_EVENTS=y
CONFIG_BT_SMP=y
CONFIG_BT_BONDABLE=y
CONFIG_LOG=y
CONFIG_LOG_BACKEND_UART=y
CONFIG_LOG_MODE_DEFERRED=y
CONFIG_LOG_PRINTK=y
CONFIG_DEBUG=y

Running this sample give this output:
[00:00:05.623,229] <inf> main: Connected: 52:E4:F6:24:85:19
[00:00:06.276,916] <wrn> main: Passkey confirmed
[00:00:06.945,007] <dbg> main: pairing_complete: Pairing complete
    /* AFTER WAITING A WHILE TO SHOW THAT THE CONNECTION IS NOT CLOSE, I POWER OFF THE PERIPHERAL */
[00:00:52.839,813] <wrn> bt_hci_core: opcode 0x200e status 0x0c
    /* THEN I SWITCH ON THE PERIPHERAL */
[00:00:59.272,674] <err> bt_l2cap: No available L2CAP context for conn 0x20000d00
[00:00:59.272,735] <err> bt_smp: No available SMP context for conn 0x20000d00
[00:00:59.272,735] <err> bt_att: No available ATT context for conn 0x20000d00
[00:00:59.272,766] <inf> main: Connected: CA:D5:C8:E6:52:E9
[00:00:59.274,169] <wrn> bt_l2cap: Ignoring data for unknown channel ID 0x0004
[00:01:00.774,047] <wrn> bt_l2cap: Ignoring data for unknown channel ID 0x0006

As we can see, at the beginning, the central connected successfully with the peripheral, the pairing and the bonding were made.
But when I disconnect the peripheral, I get the error I just describe above.
The peripheral requires a connection secure with, at least, the security level 3. The connection lives 30 seconds before being terminated by the peripheral and the errors above keep printed every 30 seconds.
When reading the Zephyr's documentation about the bt_le_set_auto_conn(), I saw that the auto connect feature is disabled during explicit scanning. However I stop the scanning process just before connecting to the peripheral and I did not restart it except if the connected initialization failed..
What I tried
I tried to call bt_le_set_auto_conn() from different places (In parse_data_cb just before the bt_conn_le_create(), where is it in the sample I provide, after the connection is initialized (i.e. in the connected_cb() callback))
I tried to use my smartphone as a peripheral (using nRF Connect app for Android), it didn't work either.
More info about the setup
My BLE central is a nRF52840-DK running a native Zephyr v3.7.0 (For some reasons I won't explain, I'm using only Zephyr, without the nRF SDK).
I know the BLE peripheral use a nRF52840, however I can't give you more info on it except that the only thing I can physically do with this device is switching the power on and off.
My questions
Why the disconnected_cb callback isn't called when the auto connect feature is enable (It is called when I disabled the auto connect feature) ? Primarily, is it the normal behavior or should I raise an issue on the Zephyr's GitHub ?
Why does this bt_hci_core error show up when the peripheral disconnect ?
I've confirmed that the connected callback is called on reconnection and that the condition conn == default_conn is true, meaning the bt_conn_set_security() must be called (and returning 0 (success) otherwise the returned value should be print). If so, why the security level isn't update/used ?
